# Loopbackjs ChangeStream not firing any update on Angularjs

Tags: angularjs, loopbackjs

I'm using [Angular Live Set](https://github.com/strongloop/angular-live-set/) in my application, but despite using the code provided in the demo, I am not receiving any event in my controller.

```
var changeStreamUrl = '/api/todo/change-stream?_format=event-source';
var src = new EventSource(changeStreamUrl);
var changes = createChangeStream(src);

changes.on('data', function (update) {
  console.log('new data');
});

changes.on('error', function (update) {
  console.log('error data');
});

changes.on('end', function (update) {
  console.log('end data');
});
```

I think the problem could be the server not emitting any event: how can I debug what's wrong with the endpoint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like ChangeStream has some issue with compression.
Removing this line

```
compression": {},
```

from `middleware.json` fixed the issue.

[Source](https://groups.google.com/d/msg/loopbackjs/HUtfcsH6wC8/VTn6RszgEAAJ)